# How to block 2 finger gestures on an entire view on iOS

Tags: ios, swift, uigesturerecognizer, scenekit

I am currently using SceneKit's default camera, and I want to continue to use the single tap and single swipe gestures but I want to prevent the default 2 finger zoom, pan, and rotation.

Is there a way to catch all 2 touch gestures performed on a view (I guess the parent view of the SceneView)  and cancel them out, without disabling 1 touch gestures?

scnView.defaultCameraController's documentation is lacking, and it looks like you can control the roll, etc. but not prevent it from occurring.

```
private func createCamera() {
        scnView.allowsCameraControl = true

        cameraNode = SCNNode()
        cameraNode.camera = SCNCamera()
        if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
            scnView.defaultCameraController.maximumVerticalAngle = 30
            scnView.defaultCameraController.minimumVerticalAngle = -30
        }
        cameraNode.position = SCNVector3(x: 0, y: 0, z: 5)
        myScene.rootNode.addChildNode(cameraNode)
    }
```

Comment: I'm not sure if you can work around that, but it's much easier IMO just to create a camera class and work from there.  Post: 57586437 should help.

Answer (score 0):

Also - once you build your own camera - you can test for the number of touches - not all code included, but something like:

```
func dragBegins(vRecognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer)
    {
        if(data.gameState == .run)
        {
            if(vRecognizer.numberOfTouches == 2) { dragMode = .strafe }
        }
    }
```

You can use the recognizer states such as .began, .changed, .ended to examine the flow and control it.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable specific gestures on a `SNView` by iterating through them and setting `isEnabled = false` on the ones you don't want enabled.

In this example I'm disabling the `UIRotationGestureRecogizer` (2 finger rotation) when initialising the `SNView`

```swift
public lazy var sceneView: SCNView = {
  let sv = SCNView()
  sv.allowsCameraControl = true
        
  sv.gestureRecognizers?.forEach({ gesture in
    if let gesture = gesture as? UIRotationGestureRecognizer {
      gesture.isEnabled = false
    }
  })

  sv.scene = self.scene
  return sv
 }()
```